# neo4j match in list if exists or not exists

Tags: neo4j

i have a list like

> ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']

i need a query to match items in graph so if item not exist i need to return NULL 
instead of remove it.

i tried this code but its not work

```
MATCH (e:Person)
WHERE e.text IN ['text1', 'text2', 'text3']
RETURN e.text, ID(e)
```

this code returns output like

```
'text1', 20
'text3', 90
```

but i expected output to be like

```
'text1', 20
'text2', null
'text3', 90
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case we need to UNWIND your list input into rows and then perform an OPTIONAL MATCH.

Also in the return, we need to return the unwound text value instead of attempting to get it from the node, since the node may not exist.

```
UNWIND ['text1', 'text2', 'text3'] as text
OPTIONAL MATCH (e:Person)
WHERE e.text = text
RETURN text, ID(e)
```